# How to exclude a subtree from the find command

Tags: command-line, search, find

So I'm trying to find all the mercurial repositories in my home directory

```
$ find ~ -name ".hg" -or -name ".git"
```

This works fine, but it finds a lot in the ~/.local/share/Trash subdirectory

How do I make it ignore these? Obviously there's grep -v, but it would be better not to search Trash at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the -prune option this way:

```
find ~ -path '*Trash*' -prune -or -name ".hg" -or -name ".git"
```

Comment: This really works? For me it doesn't prune all the different files with the string `Trash` in it; also this is looking for files with the exact name ".hg"; shouldn't it be something like `*.hg`?

Comment: @arrange, I take the example from the user asking the question, and modified that. And, obviously, it works for me that have done some tests.